# How to add multiple repositories with the same prefix to composer?

Tags: composer-php

Suppose you have

1. ssh://git@example.com/project/foo
2. ssh://git@example.com/project/bar
3. ssh://git@example.com/project/baz

And you want to add `project/foo`, `project/bar`, `project/baz` as dependencies. Configuring each with `composer config repositories.project/foo git ssh://git@example.com/project/foo` doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for packages with the same prefix - each repository must be defined separately, and in this case one repository can contain only one package.

If you have many private packages, you should probably switch to [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) or [Private Packagist](https://packagist.com/).